# How to change property name in array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects -

```
const obj = [{name:'josh', city:'Sydney'},{name:'alice', city:'York'}]
```

I want to change 'city' property to 'town'. How can I make this change to the property of each object in the array?

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [ { name: 'josh', city: 'Sydney' }, { name: 'alice', city: 'York' } ];

const res = arr.map(({ city, ...e }) => ({ ...e, town: city }));

console.log(res);
```

Using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const arr = [ { name: 'josh', city: 'Sydney' }, { name: 'alice', city: 'York' } ];

arr.forEach(e => {
  e.town = e.city;
  delete e.city;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify the key in place..?? I mean without creating another array...??

Comment: @p4avinash it is not possible to *change* a property name, but you can add a new property with the same value and `delete` the old one.

Comment: @p4avinash I updated the answer with another approach

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly, but what you can do is this:

```js
const obj = [{name:'josh', city:'Sydney'},{name:'alice', city:'York'}]
for (let element of obj){
  element.town = element.city;
  delete element.city;
}
```